# Install shared pyenv versions available to all users

Tags: python, pyenv

I have a shell server, occupied by researchers all working on their own projects, with their own required versions of python and python libraries.  There is a lot of overlap though, particularly in the versions of python required, and I have found that we're wasting a lot of space in home directories with **many** multiple copies of the same versions of python installed.

I would like to find a decent way to install pyenv `versions` globally, and allow all users to find/use them for their own `envs`.  It seems like pyenv only uses PYENV_ROOT to find where versions are installed, and doesn't have an independent PATH-like variable for allowing multiple search paths for versions.  It also puts `envs` inside the python version directories, which seems like it's probably incompatible with having shared versions.

Surely someone else has had to solve this problem before, though.  Has anyone found a way to successfully have users share pyenv versions?

Comment: Did you find a good solution @mpounsett ?

Answer (score 0):

At this time (October 2020), the directory ~/.pyenv/versions lists the Python versions available for the user:

```
> ls ~/.pyenv/versions
2.7.18  3.5.9  3.6.10  3.7.7  3.8.3  3.8.5  venv3.7
```

You can share the whole ~/.pyenv/versions directory content, or individual versions, using soft links pointing to where the actual content is.

```
> ln -s ~someotheruser/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5 ~/.pyenv/versions/my3.8
> ln -s /some_shared_dir/3.5.9 ~/.pyenv/versions/my3.5
```

Notice that all users that share a version may be affected by actions of other users that share that version.

Comment: Since environments are stored inside the version directory, doesn't that prevent users from creating an environment based on a version that's owned by another user?  That would seem to defeat the purpose of my question.  My question addressed this problem.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Python versions would be globally installed, managed by a privileged user and common users would have write access only to the version directory. The problem I see with this hack is that the access rights to the several versions must be too open.  All of this is a really dangerous mess.  I have used this hack for a very short while, but had no real need for it except for my obsession to avoid file duplications. Then I realized that I was in the way of doom... I gave an answer to your question, but I suggest you try other ways to approach your problem.

Comment: @mpounsett, did you make any progress on coercing pyenv to install python versions in a shared system location separate from where individual users' environments are stored? There's this suggestion: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/820#issuecomment-638485737

Comment: Not in any way that's useful.  Since pyenv's environments are created inside the enclosing version folder, shared versions seem to be useless.